# Rails 4: text_field helper and multidimensional params attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= text_field :foo, :bar %>
```

will generate

```
<input id="foo_bar" name="foo[bar]" type="text">
```

But what I actually want is

```
<input id="form_foo_bar" name="form[foo][bar]" type="text">
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do,

```
<%= text_field :foo, :bar, :name => "form[foo][bar]" %>
```

not tried, but should work,

```
<%= text_field "", "form[foo][bar]" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with Rails form helpers:

```
<%= form_for :form do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for(:foo) do |foo| %>
    <%= foo.text_field :bar %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```